# How do i implement login with FastAPI /token endpoint in Flutter? FastAPI(JWT + OAuth) Frontend & Flutter Backend

Tags: python, flutter, fastapi

Been trying for days to implement `login` with the `/token` endpoint from fastAPI in my flutter app I have checked many tutorials online but none seems to show how to do it correctly when using JWT and OAuth. I decided to go with Dio uisng `fullstacks tutorial on youtube` i was able to understand Dio and implement it in my app. But i get this error in flutter when i hit the login button:

```
error: {detail: [{loc: [body, username], msg: field required, type: value_error.missing},
```

And this error on fastAPI:

```
"POST /token HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

My flutter `login.dart` looks like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../dio/dio_client.dart';
import '../../dio/dio_token_manager.dart';
import 'logout.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _controllerUsername = TextEditingController();
  final _controllerPassword = TextEditingController();
  var _username = '', _password = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    () async {
      DioClient.dio.interceptors.add(TokenManager.instance);
      await checkLogin();
    }();
  }
  Future<void> checkLogin() async {
    try {
      var response = await DioClient.dio.get('http://10.0.2.2:8000/token');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LogoutScreen()));
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Status code: ${e.response?.statusCode}");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
                validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Username Required' : null,
                onSaved: (val) => _username = val!,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                controller: _controllerUsername,
                autocorrect: false,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                obscureText: true,
                validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Password Required' : null,
                onSaved: (val) => _password = val!,
                controller: _controllerPassword,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                autocorrect: false,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final form = _formKey.currentState;
                  if (form!.validate()) {
                    form.save();
                    final snackbar = SnackBar(
                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 30),
                      content: Row( 
                        children: const [
                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          Text("  Logging In...")
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
                    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
                    try {
                      final body = {
                        "username": _username,
                        "password": _password,
                      };
                      var response = await DioClient.dio.post(
                        'http://10.0.2.2:8000/token',
                        //data: jsonEncode(body),
                         data: {
                           "username": _username,
                           "password": _password,
                         },
                      );
                      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (_) => const LogoutScreen()));
                      }
                    } on DioError catch (e) {
                      debugPrint("error: ${e.response?.data}");
                    }
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Log In'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

From the fastAPI `localhost:8000/docs`, the /token endpoint returns the `200 OK` response  if you are testing the API on insomnia or postman but does not work when you try to implement the same logic on a frontend app like flutter. The fastAPI return the json with an **access_token**:

```
 {
  "access_token": "string",
  "token_type": "string"
}
```

The code for the fastAPI endpoints comes from this default [FastAPI Docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/) with username as **johndoe**

For the **Dio_token_manager.dart** :

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class TokenManager extends Interceptor {
  static final TokenManager _instance = TokenManager._internal();
  static TokenManager get instance => _instance;
  TokenManager._internal();
  String? _token;
  @override
  void onResponse(
    Response response,
    ResponseInterceptorHandler handler,
  ) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(response.data);
      if (data['set-token'] != null) {
        saveToken(data['token']);
      }
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      clearToken();
    }
    super.onResponse(response, handler);
  }

  @override
  void onRequest(
    RequestOptions options,
    RequestInterceptorHandler handler,
  ) {
    options.headers['Token'] = _token;
    return super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

  Future<void> initToken() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _token = prefs.getString('token');
  }

  void saveToken(String newToken) async {
    debugPrint('new token $newToken');
    if (_token != newToken) {
      _token = newToken;
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setString('token', _token!);
    }
  }
```

So for the **dio_client.dart**

```
class DioClient {
  static Dio dio = Dio();
  static const baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8000";
  static const productsEndpoint = "$baseUrl/products";}
```

What i have tried so far:

1. I tried adding the jsonEncode to the data as can be seen from the commented code in the login code.
2. I tried adding headers to the `dioClient.post` but it still doesnt work.

The fastAPI login route:

```
@app.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user = authenticate_user(fake_users_db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

The backend works just fine i think. Maybe there is something i am not doing right. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Since `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` expects it data as POST _form_ variables, not as JSON. See the "Sending form data" example in the dio documentation for how to convert it and try that instead: https://pub.dev/packages/dio. `var formData = FormData.fromMap(...);` then use that as the `data:` value.

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2PasswordRequestForm expects its data as POST form variables, not as JSON.

You can change the format sent by referencing the example given in the dio documentation for [how to "Send form data" instead](https://pub.dev/packages/dio):

```
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'name': 'wendux',
  'age': 25,
});
var response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);
```

In your case this would reference the username/password variables instead:

```
final body = FormData.fromMap({
  "username": _username,
  "password": _password,
});

var response = await DioClient.dio.post(
  'http://10.0.2.2:8000/token',
  data: body,
);
```